# Неизвестная ошибка SQL, в psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, telegram-bot

Я создал запрос, который должен забирать данные из базы данных PostgreSQL и помещать их в список. Затем по этому списку проходится цикл и некоторые данные помещает в переменные, которые затем переходят в другую часть кода. Проблема именно в этой части кода. Происходит какая-то ошибка, но какая - не выводится. Как можно узнать где именно ошибка и как её исправить? Вот код:

```
try:
    con = psycopg2.connect(
            host = host,
            user = user,
            password = password,
            database = db_name
        )
    con.autocommit = True

    async with con.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM native_city WHERE user_id = {}""", (user))
        data_dict = cur.fetchall()
        for data in data_dict:
            nat_city = data[1]
            area = data[2]

except Exception as _ex:
    print('[INFO] Error while working with PostgreSQL', _ex)
    print('[INFO] exception TYPE', type(_ex))
finally:
    if con:
        con.close()
        print('[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed')
```

Вот что выводится в консоль:

```
[INFO] PostgreSQL connection closed
Подключение к БД выполнено успешно
[INFO] Error while working with PostgreSQL 
[INFO] exception TYPE <class 'psycopg2.OperationalError'>
```

Начинаю предполагать, что ошибка может быть в этой части кода:

```
async def native_city_conclusion(mode, callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):

    user = callback_query.from_user.id
    try:
        await database.native_city_sqlite(user)

        city(database.nat_city, mode, database.area)

        if mode.lower() == 'завтра':
            with open('weather_tomorrow.json',  encoding='utf-8') as file:
                data_weather = json.load(file)

                for k, v in data_weather.items():
                    weather_data = f"{k}: {v}"

                    await bot.send_message(user, weather_data)
        
        elif mode.lower() == 'сегодня':
            with open('weather_today.json',  encoding='utf-8') as file:
                data_weather = json.load(file)

                for k, v in data_weather.items():
                    weather_data = f"{k}: {v}"

                    await bot.send_message(user, weather_data)

        elif mode.lower() == 'месяц':
            with open('weather_30day.json',  encoding='utf-8') as file:
                data_weather = json.load(file)

                for k, v in data_weather.items():
                    weather_data = f"{k}: {v}"

                    await bot.send_message(user, weather_data)

    except Exception as _ex:
        print(_ex)
        return await bot.send_message(user, "Вас нет в базе данных.")
```

Если убрать отлов exception в ней, то появляется такая ошибка:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\assoc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\assoc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\assoc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\assoc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 283, in process_update
    return await self.callback_query_handlers.notify(update.callback_query)
  File "C:\Users\assoc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "d:\Documents\Python\bots\weather_bot\bot.py", line 75, in native_today
    await native_city_conclusion(mode, callback_query)
  File "d:\Documents\Python\bots\weather_bot\bot.py", line 24, in native_city_conclusion
    await database.native_city_sqlite(user)
  File "d:\Documents\Python\bots\weather_bot\database.py", line 74, in native_city_sqlite
    if con:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'con' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Странно, что сам эксепшен не напечатался всё-таки.

Comment: Я использовал try в другой части когда и мне вывелась новая ошибка, возможно она пошла прямо за этой. local variable 'con' referenced before assignment

Comment: Если ругается на `con`, значит у вас `connect` не сработал.

Comment: Есть предположения, по какой причине?

Comment: Я бы всё-таки попытался разобраться, почему не напечатался `_ex`, это очень странно. Что-то там должно быть. Может вы предыдущую редакцию кода запускали, без этой печати? В эксепшене всё должно быть написано в чём причина. Либо попробуйте вообще не ловить эксепшен, может тогда трейс напечатает.

Comment: Что выдает программа, если не оборачивать в  try/except?

Comment: Вообще ничего не выдаёт

Comment: if con:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'con' referenced before assignment
Какая-то проблема с подключением к бд.